# Python Pandas get_dummies() limitation. Doesnt convert all columns

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have 6 columns in my dataframe. 2 of them have about 3K unique values. When I use `get_dummies()` on the entire dataframe or just one those 2 columns what gets returned is the exact same column with 3k values. `get_dummies` fails to dummy-fy the bigger columns. 
Some columns do get one-hot encoded but the big ones dont.

I wonder if get_dummies only works on sets with small cardinality.

I believe this was also discusses here:  [Need help with python(pandas) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057694/need-help-with-pythonpandas-script#comment66274933_25057694)

Comment: What are the dtypes? If that column with 3k unique values is of type integer it will be discarded in pd.get_dummies, yes. You can convert it to category and apply pd.get_dummies (`df['x'] = df['x'].astype('category')`). If the number of unique values are small compared to the length of the dataframe, it will use considerably less memory too.

Comment: ah that was the mistake ! Those big columns are int (factors like R has). I'll change the type ! Thanks !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to work as intended for me.

Consider the series `s` of random 3 character strings

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import lowercase

np.random.seed([3,1415])
s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list(lowercase), (10000, 3))).sum(1)

s.nunique()

7583
```

Then assign the dataframe `df`

```
df = s.str.get_dummies()
```

---

```
df.shape

(10000, 7583)
```

---

```
df.sum(1).describe()

count    10000.0
mean         1.0
std          0.0
min          1.0
25%          1.0
50%          1.0
75%          1.0
max          1.0
dtype: float64
```